# What is the equation of state of foam, on a macroscopic scale?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, pressure, density, bubbles, liquid-state

Consider a large amount of soap foam (or any other substance producing *foam*), of mass density $\rho$ *in a gravityless environment*.  What is the *internal pressure* $p$ of that foam, viewed as a fluid on a large scale, in relation with its density?
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
p(\rho) = \: ?
\end{equation}
I'm not interested in the air or liquid pressure inside the small scale bubbles.  I'm only interested in the large scale (or "macroscopic") properties of the foam considered as a smooth entity, without knowing the "microscopic" details (i.e bubbles size and their internal pressure, etc).  What should be the general expression for (1), maybe with "thermodynamic-like" parameters depending on the microscopic details?